# Wordpress install on https://www domain

Tags: wordpress, ssl, web, https

How can I install WordPress on my https://www domain ?
I installed as normal method but its not working!
I used this code for redirecting to https and www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bloom\.pk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.bloom.pk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: You need to be much more precise with "is not working".

Comment: Do you the subdomain "www" as an alias of the main domain?